# Estimate for the diameter of the image of a holomorphic disk by the area of the holomorphic disk

Tags: complex-geometry, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Let $(M, J, g)$ be a compact almost complex manifold with a Riemannian metric $g$ that preserves the almost complex structure $J$. I want to prove that a holomorphic disk $u: D^2\to M$ of a small area $Area(u)$ can't have a big diameter. Is there a way to give a bound on the diameter of $u(D^2)$ in terms of the area $Area(u)$?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but could the monotonicity formula help? Cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107468/j-holomorphic-curve-as-a-minimal-surface

Comment: This is certainly not true. Even when $M$ is the ordinary Riemann sphere, with standard holomorphic structure. You can have a conformal map $D^2\to S$ whose image has arbitrarily small area, and fixed diameter.

Comment: @LeoMoos monotonicity formula will not apply in case the disk u has a thin but long image (big diameter), so the image of u cant be enclosed in a small ball even if u have a very small area. As Alexander pointed out such disks u exist in S^2, thanks LeoMoos, and Alexander for your helpful comments  .......